# Find the derivative of $\arccos\frac{b+a\cos x}{a+b\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of $\arccos\dfrac{b+a\cos x}{a+b\cos x}$

is there a smart way to find this derivative

i tried by the conventional chain rule way, and it got very complicated

Comment: There are certainly other ways to do it, for example you can take the cosine of both sides and apply the quotient rule to the right and chain rule to the left then solve for y', similar in fashion to using the natural log on fractions

Comment: @Dan what you are suggesting boils down to derivating $\arccos$

Comment: Differentiating, but yes, that's why I said it. One may avoid the arccosine term but pays the price elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

It is not *too* complicated if one goes through the chain rule of derivatives.

$$\begin{split}\arccos \left( {\frac{{b + a\cos x}}{{a + b\cos x}}} \right) &= \arccos \left( u \right) = F\left( {u\left( x \right)} \right)\\
u &= \frac{{b + a\cos x}}{{a + b\cos x}}\\
\frac{{dF}}{{dx}} &= \frac{{dF}}{{du}}\frac{{du}}{{dx}}
\end{split}
$$

$$\frac{{dF}}{{du}} =  - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - {u^2}} }} =  - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - {{\left( {\frac{{b + a\cos x}}{{a + b\cos x}}} \right)}^2}} }}
$$

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{{du}}{{dx}} &= \frac{{\left( { - a\sin x} \right)\left( {a + b\cos x} \right) - \left( {b + a\cos x} \right)\left( { - b\sin x} \right)}}{{{{\left( {a + b\cos x} \right)}^2}}}\\
&= \frac{1}{{{{\left( {a + b\cos x} \right)}^2}}}\left[ { - {a^2}\sin x - ab\sin x\cos x + {b^2}sinx + ab\sin x\cos x} \right]\\ &= \frac{1}{{{{\left( {a + b\cos x} \right)}^2}}}\left[ { - {a^2}\sin x + {b^2}sinx} \right]\\
&= \frac{{\left( {{b^2} - {a^2}} \right)\sin x}}{{{{\left( {a + b\cos x} \right)}^2}}}\end{split}
$$

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{{dF}}{{dx}} = \frac{{dF}}{{du}}\frac{{du}}{{dx}} &=  - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - {{\left( {\frac{{b + a\cos x}}{{a + b\cos x}}} \right)}^2}} }}\frac{{\left( {{b^2} - {a^2}} \right)\sin x}}{{{{\left( {a + b\cos x} \right)}^2}}}\\ &=  - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {{{\left( {a + b\cos x} \right)}^2} - {{\left( {b + a\cos x} \right)}^2}} }}\frac{{\left( {{b^2} - {a^2}} \right)\sin x}}{{\left|{a + b\cos x}\right|}} \\&= {\mathop{\rm sgn}} \left( {\sin x} \right)\frac{{\sqrt {{a^2} - {b^2}} }}{{\left| {a + b\cos x} \right|}}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: The square root simplifies to $\sqrt{|a^2-b^2|}|\sin x|$

Comment: @marwalix then the function can be more simplified to: ${\mathop{\rm sgn}} \left( {\sin x} \right)\frac{{\sqrt {{a^2} - {b^2}} }}{{\left| {a + b\cos x} \right|}}$

Answer (score 0):

No clever way in my view but with some order one finds
$$f'(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{|a^2-b^2|}}{a+b\cos x}$$